# iPhone webapp: input keyboard moves page up

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, web-applications

I have a page with four inputs on it and when I click either of the two bottom ones the whole page moves up to make room for the keyboard, but the odd thing is that there is already room for the keyboard, yet the whole page still moves. Here is a picture:

[image]
[image]

Right now I am using an event listener to set document.body.scrollTop to 0 onfocus. It works, but it still moves up before jumping back to normal.

I am wonder if there is a way to fix this and not have it move up at all.